# Finding Probability of picking one ball out of N balls.

Tags: probability, statistics, sampling

presented with n identical balls, one with a prize in it. Picks each ball out  idependently one at a time till gets prize. I need to find the mean and variance of the number of balls needed to pick out the prize, if the balls are not replaced.

I can work it out with replacement, and i have been told to not work it out with hypergeometric series.

I know that there are going to be $\frac{n!}{2(n-2)!}$ combinations due to the formula for unordered non replacment.

I'm thinking so far it has to also do with the series from $k= 1 \ldots n$ of $\frac{1}{k} + \frac{1}{k}\frac{1}{(k-1)} + \frac{1}{k}\frac{1}{(k-1)}\frac{1}{(k-2)}$ etc but I can't think of a way to neaten that series either.

Please help!

Comment: Hint:  compute the probability that it take one draw.  Then two draws.  Then three.  Look for a pattern.

Comment: struggling to find the pattern

Comment: What's the probability that you get it in one?  two?

Comment: 1/n and 2/n-1 didn't mean to put k

Comment: $\frac 1n$ is correct, but the other isn't.  Why would it be (roughly) twice as likely that the winner be in the second slot?  To be in the second slot you need the first slot to be a loser (probability $\frac {n-1}{n}$) then you need the second to be the winner (probability $\frac {1}{n-1}$).

Comment: Sorry i derped, it would be 1/n and 1/n*1/n-1 = 1/n^2-1

Comment: No...think about it.  With $n=100$ you are suggesting that it is roughly $100$ times more likely that the ball is in the first slot than in the second.  Why would that be?

Comment: true true. 1/n, 1/n

Comment: Ah, good.  Have you spotted the (not especially subtle) pattern?

Comment: Yep I have, thanks

Comment: one small remark...while drawing the $(n-1)$st ball you will know where the prize is, no matter if the $(n-1)$st ball was a loser or a winner, so you don't have to draw the last ball at all

Comment: Yeah I mentally acknowledged that one already, thanks user190080

Comment: so does this mean that the mean is just the sum of 1/n + 2/n + 3/n etc up to n

Comment: Indeed it does.  The distribution is uniform...the winner has an equal chance of being in any of the slots.

Comment: any tips on computing that? or am i going to go on a quest to find out what it converges to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ be the random variable equal to the number of balls that must be picked to win the prize.

As long as the winning ball has not been picked, the probability to get the winning ball at the $k$-th pick is the product of the probabilities *not to win* at the first pick, at the second pick, &c., at the $k-1$-th pick, and finally to win at the $k$-th pick. As there is one less ball after each pick, using the formula of composed probabilities, this gives:
$$P(X=k)=\frac{n-1}{n}\cdot\frac{n-2}{n-1}\dotsm\frac{n-k+1}{n-k+2}\cdot\frac1{n-k+1}=\frac1n$$
Thus the law of $X$ is the *uniform law*, and it is known that:
$$E(X)=\frac{n+1}2,\quad V(X)=\frac{n^2-1}{12}.$$